# ImageButton displays differently when created dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `GridLayout`-based View to which I am dynamically adding several `ImageButton`s. I'm trying to understand why the ImageButtons are styled correctly when I inflate them from a layout xml file, but not when I create them using the ImageButton constructor directly.

The GridLayout and ImageButtons were previously both defined in the same layout .xml file (and rendered as expected):

```
<ScrollView 
    style="@style/my_list_style"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="12dp">

        <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/my_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

            <!-- These ImageButtons are being converted to dynamic. --> 
            <ImageButton
                style="@style/my_button_style"
                android:src="@drawable/image1" />

            <ImageButton
                style="@style/my_button_style"
                android:src="@drawable/image2" />

        </GridLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

To convert the ImageButtons to dynamic, I first removed them from the layout file and used code like the following to add them at runtime:

```
ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton(context, null, R.style.my_button_style);
imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
parent.addView(imageButton);
```

But the buttons failed to render properly; they are not centered, and their sizes do not appear to be correct/uniform.

I then tried creating a new layout file, containing nothing but the ImageButton and its style:

```
<ImageButton
    style="@style/my_button_style"/>
```

When I inflate this layout into the GridView at runtime, everything looks as expected:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) inflater.inflate(
    R.layout.my_button_layout, parent, false);
imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
parent.addView(imageButton);
```

Why does inflating the view with LayoutInflator give different results than creating the button directly from its constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you create `ImageButton` manually, you do not specify its parent, hence it doesn't know the layout params of its parent and can't be laid out as you expect.

On the other hand, when you inflate it via `LayoutInflater`, you are specifying the `parent`. Then correct layout params are being passed to children. That's why you see difference.

Have a look at [detailed article](https://possiblemobile.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/) by Dave Smith.

Comment: It wasn't obvious to me that the LayoutParams of the parent couldn't be inferred by the framework when I called `addView`. Apparently this has to happen at the time of View instantiation. Thanks for the link.